# Xcode: Signing the app fails as a team member

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

My manager has created an account for me with Admin access. He created an App with an specific bundle ID on the portal, say `com.name.app1`. I have created a project with the same bundle ID and chose the new account under Team. But it fails to sign and says:

> Failed to register bundle identifier.
>
> No profiles for 'com.name.app1' were found

[image]

There is a registered identifier with that ID on the portal. What are we doing wrong here? How can I develop that app as a team member?

Comment: The first message means that that bundle id is associated with some other team (or possibly your team but you can't see it). The second message arises because of the first.

Comment: Yeah, the thing is I can see the app in iTunesConnect

Comment: Yeah, but this message refers to the developer.apple.com portal; that is where provisioning profiles are registered.  AppStore connect only comes into it when you are ready to upload a build for distribution

Comment: the ID is. registered there too, and i'm my role is admin. it does not make sense.

Comment: If there is already a provisioning profile registered, download it into Xcode and switch to manual signing to see if that resolves the issue

Comment: @Paulw11 my manager should download it, yeah.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's weird but I had to remove my own account from the Xcode then I could sign the app with the team's provisioning profile, a new profile showed up after removing my personal account.

Answer (score 0):

you need download or update your provisioning profile. if you already have profile, remove from keychain your profile after download and update him.

Comment: did you try sign in automatically?

Comment: I tried same case and works successfully. 
I create a new project.
Select same team.
set same build id.

Answer (score 0):

You are a member of more than one team. This identifier was registered to one team and you are trying to sign it with a different team. Every developer with a paid account is a member of at least two teams, a personal team and the paid account team. From there you can be invited to many more teams. (I’m a member of about two dozen teams.)

Try switching to the other team in the signing section for this target.

Upon confirming the correct team is selected and this continues to occur, maybe something is corrupted in your account. Try deleting the teams from Xcode and reloading them. In Xcode’s preferences remove all accounts. Then delete any provisioning profiles (stored in `~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles`). Then log back into the account and download the provisioning profiles.

Comment: I did try that too, it's obvious that i should choose the right team